# I made a some set state and I dont know what did work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hellow everyone, I running `typeScript` in my application, I create a simple interface like that, and a state

```
//Interface
interface ICardList {
 title: string;
 istItens: IlistItens[];
}

interface IlistItens {
 name: string;
 isChecked: boolean;
}
//In Function
const [listContent, setListContent] = useState<ICardList[]>();
```

And in another component I create a simple function when user type something, the state update

```
  const updateTitleTable = (value: string, index: number) => {
   let listJson = listContent;

   listJson[index].title = value;

   setListContent([...listContent]);
  };
```

Ok, now the whats really import, why this work and theses codes bellow dont work

```
//Try one
const updateTitleTable = (value: string, index: number) => {
  let listJson = listContent;

  listJson[index].title = value;

  setListContent(listJson);
};

 //Try tow
 const updateTitleTable = (value: string, index: number) => {
   listContent[index].title = value;

   setListContent(listContent);
 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mutating the array in place, which is a big no-no, since React won't "notice" the object having changed, since you're just assigning the same object back to the state.

You'll need to copy the list, then copy the object you're mutating, then assign back to the copied list, then `setState` with the copied list.

```
const updateTitleTable = (value: string, index: number) => {
  const newList = [...listContent]; // Shallow copy
  const newObject = {...listContent[index], title: value}; // Shallow copy with assignment
  newList[index] = newObject;
  setListContent(newList);
};
```

For modifications such as this, it's better to use [the functional form of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) (where you get the old state atom as an argument and return the new value):

```
const updateTitleTable = (value: string, index: number) => {
  setListContent(listContent => {
    const newList = [...listContent]; // Shallow copy
    const newObject = {...listContent[index], title: value}; // Shallow copy with assignment
    newList[index] = newObject;
    return newList;
  });
};
```

Comment: this answers question, thanks for the resolution. ❤